# Using dplyr, group data by id and date, find first and last location

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

EDIT: Sorry, it seems my example data was too simple/nice. The full data set is much larger. I cannot recover the order of events by ordering by date or anything else. And the on and off are ids, not event numbers, so do not have an order either. I've updated the example to better reflect this.

Here is some example data:

```
ids <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)
date <- c(1,1,1, 3,3,3)
off <- c(234,234,93, 675,876,876) # these are ids
on <- c(93,111,234, 876,675,675) # these are ids

df <- data.frame(ids, dates, on, off)
```

This represents journeys, ie
individual 1 goes from 234 -> 93 -> 234 -> 111
individual 2 goes from 876 -> 675 -> 876 -> 675

The date information is not detailed enough to order the records on their own. I cannot just take first and last.

Grouping the data by id and date, and I want identify where the first off location was, and the last on location was, and aggregate this into one record.

I would expect an outcome in this instance of

```
ids <- c(1, 2)
date <- c(1,3)
off <- c(234, 111)
on <- c(876, 675)
```

I have tried many things but none have worked correctly.

Comment: This is not uniformly identifiable, because in each group there are n paths and you do not know where the individual started. For example, you have the rows [[10, 25], [25, 30], [30, 10]], which can lead to 2 possible paths, namely starting in the first row leads to 10->25->30->10 and starting in the second row leads to 25->30->10->25.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your logic is that for each id, you just want the minimum value for off and the maximum value for on, so this should do it.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
ids <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2)
date <- c(1,1,1, 3,3,3)
off <- c(111,234,111, 675,876,675)
on <- c(234,111,876, 876,675,876)

df <- data.frame(ids = ids, date = date, on = on, off = off)
df %>%
  group_by(ids) %>%
  filter(on == max(on), off == min(off)) %>%
  distinct()
#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#> # Groups:   ids [2]
#>     ids  date    on   off
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1   876   111
#> 2     2     3   876   675
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Your output doesn't match the expected sorry. I've also just updated the question to make the issue clearer.

Answer (score 0):

you may also use `group_by` and `slice_head`

```r
data.frame(ids, date, on, off) %>% arrange(ids,date, on, off) %>% group_by(ids) %>% 
slice_head(n=1)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 2 × 4
# Groups:   ids [2]
    ids  date    on   off
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1   111   234
2     2     3   675   876
```

Comment: Sorry, in the real data I can't rely on date to order the records. I've also just updated the question to make the issue clearer.

Answer (score 0):

The first and last line of each group determines the beginning and the end. Therefore, select them and summarize the data. For example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(ids, date) %>% 
  mutate(start = case_when(row_number() == 1 ~ off),
         end = case_when(row_number() == n() ~ on)) %>% 
  select(-on, -off) %>% 
  filter(!(is.na(start) & is.na(end))) %>% 
  fill(start, .direction="down") %>% 
  fill(end, .direction="up") %>% 
  distinct()
```

This ends up with:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 4
# Groups:   ids, date [2]
    ids  date start   end
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1   111   876
2     2     3   675   876
```

Comment: Sorry, in the real data I can't rely on the records to be in the right order, and there is no way to order them. I've also just updated the question to make the issue clearer.